# Datatable to List and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, extension-methods

I created an extension method to convert a datatable to list and list to datatable. I have multiple problems with this. can someone help me fix the issues please:

1. Both datatable columns and the generic class property names needs to be the same even and case sensitive. I need to modify this to handle the situation where case is not taken into consideration ex: EmployeeName = employeename.
2. If the generic class has a complex type as a property then my function does not seem to work. ex: if i have Public string EmployeeName {get; set;} my code works, but if i have Public Department DepartmentDetails {get; set;} ( know this one is a bit tricky but if someone can give me a suggestion how to handle this at all, i shall be glad.)

Please find below my Extension method.

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            var dataList = new List<T>();

            const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var propertyList = (from PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties(flags)
                                select new
                                {
                                    Name = property.Name,
                                    Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType
                                }).ToList();

            var dataTableFieldNames = (from DataColumn columnHeader in table.Columns
                                       select new { Name = columnHeader.ColumnName, Type = columnHeader.DataType }).ToList();

            var commonProperties = propertyList.Intersect(dataTableFieldNames).ToList();

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in table.AsEnumerable().ToList())
            {
                var templateType = new T();
                foreach (var field in commonProperties)
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfos = templateType.GetType().GetProperty(field.Name);
                    propertyInfos.SetValue(templateType, dataRow[field.Name], null);
                }
                dataList.Add(templateType);
            }
            return dataList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both datatable columns and the generic class property names needs to be the same even and case sensitive. I need to modify this to handle the situation where case is not taken into consideration ex: EmployeeName = employeename.

That part is easy. You can compare the Name's case-insensitively:

```
var commonProperties = propertyList
  .Where(p => dataTableFieldNames
            .Any(d => string.Equals(d.Name, p.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                      d.Type == p.Type).ToList();
```

> If the generic class has a complex type as a property then my function does not seem to work.

Now that is a bit hard and depends on what would you like to do in that situation? Does your `DataTable` also contains columns that belongs the other types (e.g. `Departmant`) ? If so you will need to determine which types of properties you have (additionally,other than the built-in types) and which additional columns exists in your `DataTable` for those types.Then you can get the properties of each type and map them to the columns in your `DataTable`.

Comment: First solution works for me fine. Thanks for that. Yeah you are right the second one is a bit tricky. I guess the questions is relevant but guess its a decision i need to take how to design it rather than have a common solution for such an issue.